# I am wroking Xamarin.forms and getting this error in xaml file

Tags: android, visual-studio, xaml, xamarin.forms

[image: Error: The Property "content" is set more than once]

I tried remove one child layout but didn't worked.

Comment: Obviously ContentPage can have only one Content element

Comment: Delete the first StackLayout in your page (it is empty anyways), leaving only the AbsoluteLayout which is defined after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside a `Page`, you can only have one layout element. Inside that layout element, you can have infinite nested elements.

So, everything you have now should be wrapped in a StackLayout, Grid, or similar according to your needs.

Like this:

```
<ContentPage> 
    <StackLayout>
        <!-- Your current layout -->
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Answer (score -1):

You need **ContentPage.Content**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:behaviors="clr-namespace:Prism.Behaviors;assembly=Prism.Forms"
             x:Class="WowonderPhone.Pages.WelcomePage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <!-- Place Content Here -->
            <Label Text="Hello World"/>
            <Label Text="Hello World"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: The default property inside the content page is the Content. This is not required

Comment: @GeraldVersluis so it deserves a negative because its not required ?

Comment: Who said I did that? Anyhow, this just isn't an answer. You state that the OPs error is due to the fact that he needs `ContentPage.Content` which is just not true.